# How Can I Refresh Gridview Using Slider Extender (Ajax) Using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview that is fetching data from database based on a value. There after i have one slider extender that contain a range of values . Now if that slider extender is moving in either direction the gridview automatically fetches data from database simultaneously from database on its movement , which in turn is displayed on gridview simultaneously..

Comment: The easy way is to use `update-panel` with [slider extender](http://www.ajaxtutorials.com/asp-net/learn-how-to-use-the-asp-net-ajax-slider-control-c/) [Example1](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=219).

Comment: that is fine . but the what what will be the controlid , event name of the update panel.

Comment: Have you gone through example1.